# Sequence of tenses in dialogue: why is "No, can't say I had" used in response to "Perhaps you didn't notice?"?

Tags: tenses, sequence-of-tenses, dialogue, cinema

From the movie "*No Time to Die*":

> Nomi: The world's moved on since you retired, Commander Bond. Perhaps you didn't notice?
> Bond: No, can't say I had."

Why did Bond use "had" and not "did"?

Comment: Left out from Bond's line is "noticed": "No, I can't say I had [noticed]." 1. This is understandable and unremarkable to native speakers; 2. No dialogue requires absolute attention and adherence to the grammar of the interlocutor; 3. This is screenwriting, and as such its goal is to bring to life how characters actually speak.

Comment: @Robusto so you are saying that it could (or even should) be "did", it's just how Bond chose to reply? I mean, I am not missing anything here, and there is no grammatical reason to prefer "had" over "did"? Because this is what I thought, that there must be some reason for "had" that I don't know.

Comment: "I hadn't noticed" is very common in British English. Bond uses the version more familiar to him rather than echo the more American-sounding "didn't notice".

Comment: The perfect tense is fine, but more to the point: why did he use past perfect "had" when present perfect "have" would seem appropriate.

Comment: "I haven't noticed" would suggest he hasn't noticed yet but may notice in future. "I hadn't noticed" makes it clear that he hasn't noticed and he's done looking so he won't notice in future; it has a sense of finality lacking with "have". As Kate says, "I hadn't noticed" is very common in UK English, often used as an understated way of dismissing something or disclaiming responsibility.

Comment: @moskit: No, I'm not arguing that it should be as you say. Grammar rules of sentence construction are entirely out of place here. And, I might add, the path you are going down may lead to this question being closed as opinion-based.

Comment: Note that the responder doesn't say the participle (_had **noticed**_) required with a perfect auxiliary _have_. The questioner uses the auxiliary for an infinitive (_didn't **notice**_), not a participle. Consequently, if you filled in all the missing words, it isn't  ungrammatical, just not parallel: _Perhaps you didn't notice [it]. I can't say I have noticed it._ This violates the attempt at reduction, but is clear enough. And this is a movie, not real speech.

Comment: I think Bond's use of the past perfect makes him seem more highbrow or "proper" than Nomi.

Comment: Surely a perfect example would drop the redundant parts and use only 'I didn't' in response to 'You didn't notice?' but a dozen other idioms would be wholly acceptable even outside Movieland; a score or more if common slips were allowed.

Comment: Bond: "No, can't say I had before you just pointed it out." // Most Brits use an echo auxiliary rather than a form of  _do_ in answers: "Have you brushed your teeth, Bobby? ... "Yes, I have." [not "Yes, I did."] Bond goes beyond this, eschewing even an echoing 'did'. But 'have' would be my choice too, as 'did' really points to a punctive event (Nomi's no doubt deliberate choice).

Answer (score 0):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> Note that the responder doesn't say the participle (*had **noticed***) required with a perfect auxiliary *have*. The questioner uses the auxiliary for an infinitive (*didn't **notice***), not a participle. Consequently, if you filled in all the missing words, it isn't  ungrammatical, just not parallel: *Perhaps you didn't notice [it]. I can't say I have noticed it.* This violates the attempt at reduction, but is clear enough. And this is a movie, not real speech.